# MongoDB ensurIndex and createIndex using nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, indexing, mongoose

I was not able to create index for `profile`:

```
var user = new Schema({
      profile : "String",
      fullname:"String"
   })
    user.statics.createIndexOfProfile = function(callback){
    this.ensureIndex("profile",function(err,doc){
        if(err) {
          console.log(err+'sna');
          callback(err);
        }
         else {
          console.log(doc+'santhosh');
          callback(null,doc);
        }
      });
```

I was getting error like `this.ensureIndex is not a function`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct API is [`ensureIndexes`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.ensureIndexes), which Sends `ensureIndex` commands to mongo for each `index` **declared** in the schema.

Here is one sample

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    profile : {type: String, index: true},
    fullname: String
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

User.ensureIndexes(function(err) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        console.log('create profile index successfully');
});
```

Or through [`index`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-index)

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    profile : {type: String, index: true},
    fullname: String
});

UserSchema.index({ profile: 1 });

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

After running the above codes, then check the indexes from MongoDB.

```
> db.users.getIndexes()
[
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "test.users"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "profile" : 1
                },
                "name" : "profile_1",
                "ns" : "test.users",
                "background" : true
        }
]
```

Comment: but how to search. when i do user.find({$text:{$search:"MBBS"}},function(err,doc){
      if(err)  cosnole.log(err)
      else console.log(doc)
    })

Comment: errror is like     "$err": "Unable to execute query: error processing query: ns=user.profile limit=1000 skip=0\nTree: TEXT : query=santhosh, language=, tag=NULL\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n planner returned error: need exactly one text index for $text query",

Comment: @santhosh, try `UserSchema.index({ profile: 'text' });`

Comment: @zangw , appreciate if you can have a look ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35426213/how-to-group-mongodb-mapreduce-output

Comment: by doing get index from mongo shell i was able to see the creation of index

Comment: @santhosh, may drop the previous index through `dropIndexes`, then recreate `text index` through `{profile: 'text'}`...

Comment: i'm again getting the same error:> error: need exactly one text index for $text query

Comment: @santhosh, I got it, please remove the ` index: true` from `profile`, just, `profile : {type: String},` I think it could solve your issue

Comment: @zangw this time getindexes :{
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "test.user"
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103587/discussion-between-zangw-and-santhosh).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add an index to some field, just add `index: true` to its definition.

So you can do the following:

```
var user = new Schema({
    profile : { type: String, index: true }, // field level
    // ...
});
```

or

```
user.index({ profile: 1 }); // schema level
```

From `mongoose` [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html):

> When your application starts up, Mongoose automatically calls
>   ensureIndex for each defined index in your schema. Mongoose will call
>   ensureIndex for each index sequentially, and emit an 'index' event on
>   the model when all the ensureIndex calls succeeded or when there was
>   an error.